# Customize Laravel registration process

Tags: php, laravel, registration

I want to customize the Laravel registration process.
User is unable to directly click on the link and register, instead of that I send a link to the user for registration. eg: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register?id=123
If the ID is available in customer table then get the email address against the id and redirect to Registration screen with email address.

How to change web.php file to accept parameters?
Auth::routes();

How to change the Register related controllers to accept parameters and pass values to view?

[Register screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm8a3.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isnt clear enough but i'll try.

First you have to turn off registration from the auth like so `Auth::routes(['register' => false]);`, this way users wont get access to the registration route even if the typed it in the url.

After you have done this go to your Auth\RegisterController class and take a peek into the `RedirectsUsers` trait that it uses, you will find a register method that looks like:

```
    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('', 201)
                    : redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

This is where the registration logic happens, you can customize it any way you see fit but be careful not to shoot yourself in the foot.

For the routing you can do one or two things

e.g 1

```
Route::get('/custom/registration', 'RegisterController@register')->name('register');
```

Then you can access your `id` in the controller like this:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->query('id)

    // Run your logic...
}
```

or

e.g 2

```
Route::get('/custom/registration/{id}', 'RegisterController@register')->name('register');
```

Then you can access your `id` in the controller like this:

```
public function register(Request $request, $id)
{
    
    // Run your logic...
}
```

Which ever way makes sense to you is fine.

Comment: Then create another controller and recreate the steps...if you need it to have the registration methods available in the RegisterController then use the `RegistersUsers` trait on the new controller and then override whatever you want. More like copy and past the Register Controller then rename it.

Comment: Your answer was helpful but I don't want to override the registration procedure completely. 
I did override RegisterController showRegistrationForm() to pass ID value to registration form.
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register', ["id" => 'TEST123']);
    }
}

Now I need to get this hard coded value from URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/TEST123
How to change the web.php for that?

Comment: Your route will look like this `Route::get('/register/{id}', 'RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')` then your controller method will look like this: `public function showRegistrationForm($id) { return view('auth.register', ["id" => $id]); }`

Comment: web.php

`Route::get('/register/{id}', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');`


Auth\RegisterControler.php

`class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    ....
    ...
    .

    public function showRegistrationForm($id)
    {
        return view('auth.register', ["id" => $id]);
    }
}`

It solved. Thanks.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/TEST123